# conditions on table column while selecting data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Recently while working i noticed one strange select query done by my seniors I tried to understand it but no result at last.
Query is like

```
SELECT company_name = '', customer_firstname = '', customer_lastname = '', customer_city = ''
FROM customers
```

and result is attached in snap can any body explain me the query.thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: It's comparing each column value with an empty string to return a Boolean type value indicating whether the column contains data or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison operators evaluate to `1` when the condition is true, `0` when it's false, and `NULL` if either of the arguments is a `NULL` value. So `company_name = ''` will be `1` for rows where the `company_name` column is an empty string, `0` in rows where it's not empty. The same goes for all the other items in the `SELECT` list.

So the first row in the `customers` table has an empty `company_name`. The second row has none of these columnns empty. The third row has `NULL` in `customer_lastname`.

Comment: Thank for the reply and explanation.